# Get eclipse runtime configuration keys and values

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, runtime

Hi I need to see eclipse's running configuration in a simple java project. for example print them as key value pairs at console would be enough

[EDIT]: the reason for this 
I added a parameter to eclipse.ini but I'm not sure about the value whether it is passed as I expect or not

and the parameter I'm looking for is

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=xulrunner

Comment: please elaborate on your Question.>____>----> Do you mean to get java execution configuration. Or eclipse settings from preferences. >____>----> As jigar mentioned you have the option of printing the system properties. Except I am not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I edited my question sorry for not elaborating on my question

Comment: I have put my response in answer which maybe helpful

Comment: thanks for the vote, unlocked a new priv :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse runs on a JVM, which is not the same JVM where your program will run.

It would be easier to find the configuration file (eclipse.ini I guess is what you are looking for), since they will not be environment settings for the JVM where your code will run.

Comment: actually I add a run time parameter to eclipse.ini but I'm not sure about its value whether it is passed as I expect or not

Comment: Then, check at Help > About Eclipse > Installation details and select the "Configuration" tab. There you will see all the configuration options applied to the current Eclipse instance. (This is for Eclipse Kepler, maybe it's different for older releases)

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways for getting the details

> http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-list-all-system-properties-key-and-value-in-java/

In case it is java parameters

> [Read Java JVM startup parameters (eg -Xmx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518213/read-java-jvm-startup-parameters-eg-xmx)

From your updated response.
I will suggest that you check your memory manager.

In windows that will be task manager
mac that will be Activity Monitor
on linux you can fire top command from command line

Still not satisfied, check over this StackOverflow thread

> [Monitoring own memory usage by Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754748/monitoring-own-memory-usage-by-java-application)

Still not satisfied. I would suggest profiling of the application using yourkit profiler or any other java profiler.

When you start yourkit it shows the java applications running. Simply click on one of it and it will initate profiling for you.

Comment: thanks i tried but I didn't see anything about xulrunner parameter does it normal?

Answer (score 0):

all runtime configuration endsup being a java argument or a system property passed

so you can print all the commandline argument passed in to java + all the System properties and its values (may be with filtered set of key value based on your interest)